# Identity of dimensions related to cohomology group of projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $k$ be a field, $S=k[T_0,\ldots T_r]$, $\mathbb P=\mathbb P_k^r=\operatorname{Proj}S$ and $O$ a structure sheaf of $\mathbb P$. How can I show the identity
$$\operatorname{dim}_kH^0(\mathbb P,O(n))+(-1)^r\operatorname{dim}_kH^r(\mathbb P,O(n))=\binom{n+r}{r}?$$

Comment: This should follow from a standard Cech cohomology computation. Have you looked at, uhm, 5.4 (I think?) of Hartshorne?

Comment: I don't have this book. I study algebraic geometry on my own by doing exercises on the Internet and reading the only algebraic geometry book I have, Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves.

Comment: Okay. So does the result follow from the fact that $(K[T_0,\ldots T_n])_r$ is a finite $K$-module of rank $\binom{n+r}{r}$?

Comment: I don't think it's immediate from that. For some graded modules it is not even the case that $H^0(\widetilde{M}) = M_0$, so there's something to check even for $H^0$: that the sections really are what you think they are. And you need to check $H^r$ too, which is slightly more difficult. The surprisingly tricky part is showing that the cohomologies in between vanish.

Comment: I seem to recall that Liu at least quotes the result of the computation and it's done in a bunch of online sources; e.g., [the Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01XS), [notes by McKernan](http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/11-12/Spring/18.726/l_15.pdf), and Section 18.3 of [Ravi's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/).